# Поля в инспекторе не заполняются Asset Bundle'ами

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет. Изучаю `asset bundle'ы`. Зарегал бесплатный демохостинг, загрузил туда `asset bundle`. Все загружается/скачивается нормально. Все `дебаглоги` проходят в консоль, но картинки и музыки нет, поля `AudioClip` и `Sprite` остаются пустыми. Не пойму в чем может быть причина

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class LoadScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string _bundleURL = "anyLink"; //убрал ссылку чтобы не палить пароль
    private int _version = 0;

    [SerializeField] private AudioSource _audioSource;
    [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer _renderer;

    public void OnClickDownload()
    {
        StartCoroutine(DownloadAndCache());
    }

    IEnumerator DownloadAndCache()
    {
        while (!Caching.ready)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        var www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(_bundleURL, _version);
        yield return www;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
            yield break;
        }

        Debug.Log("Бандл загружен");
        var assetBundle = www.assetBundle;
        string musicName = "duraki";
        string spriteName = "heart";

        var musicRequest = assetBundle.LoadAssetAsync(musicName, typeof(AudioClip));
        yield return musicRequest;
        Debug.Log("Музыкальный файл распакован");

        var spriteRequest = assetBundle.LoadAssetAsync(spriteName, typeof(Sprite));
        yield return spriteRequest;
        Debug.Log("Изображение распаковано");

        _audioSource.clip = musicRequest.asset as AudioClip;
        _audioSource.Play();
        Debug.Log("Музыка играет");

        _renderer.sprite = spriteRequest.asset as Sprite;
        Debug.Log("Картинка есть");
    }
}
```

Comment: а вы уверены, что, например, в musicRequest.asset что-то есть? Подключитесь своим редактором кода к юнити, поставьте брейк поинт на момент назначения и посмотрите, что там в реквестах приходит.

Comment: @M.Green действительно, что в musicRequest что в spriteRequest значение null. Видимо я неправильно его записываю?

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему, используя UnityWebRequest вместо WWW. Не знаю, что я не так делал, методом тыка и чтения документации получилось.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class LoadScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string _bundleURL = "PasteYourLinkHere";

    public void OnClickDownload()
    {
        StartCoroutine(DownloadAndCache());
    }

    [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer _spriteRenderer;
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource _audioSource;

    IEnumerator DownloadAndCache()
    {
        var www = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(_bundleURL);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        Debug.Log("Бандл загружен");

        AssetBundle assetBundle = DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(www);

        var spriteRequest = assetBundle.LoadAssetAsync<Sprite>("assets/synergy/recources/sprites/heart.png");
        yield return spriteRequest;
        
        var musicRequest = assetBundle.LoadAssetAsync<AudioClip>("assets/synergy/recources/music/duraki.mp3");
        yield return spriteRequest;

        _spriteRenderer.sprite = spriteRequest.asset as Sprite;

        _audioSource.clip = musicRequest.asset as AudioClip;
        _audioSource.Play();

    }   
}
```